# python regular expression end of match in different conditions

Tags: python, regex

Currently, I am using two regular expressions to get data from string, like as below:

```
match = re.match('(\d+(\.\d+)*)(.*)[Xx](.*)(\d+(\.\d+)*)|', '12 x 13.5|1 - 3 acres')
```

The number I want to get is 12 and 13.5.

In other situation, the string don't have |, it is just empty after the number. I use this to match:

```
match = re.match('(\d+(\.\d+)*)(.*)[Xx](.*)(\d+(\.\d+)*)$', '12 x 13.5')
```

What I want is to use one regular expression to match both of two conditions, how should I do?

update:

I get number by:

```
match.group(1)
match.group(4)+match.group(5)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Merge the lines how? And a better way than what? What's the code supposed to do?

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure that both of those regexes are incorrect. Please describe what you're trying to match.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove `|` / `$`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for your comment, I have updated the description.

Comment: @melpomene  Sorry I cant, because there is a situation: 23'x161'x53'x45'x56'x32'x56'|7,251. I don't want to match this record.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a way to match either a `|` character or the end of the string? That would be `(?:$|\|)`.

Comment: Also, `\d+(\.\d+)*` matches things like `1.2.3.4.5`. You don't want to match an arbitrary number of decimals; you want to match 0 or 1. Use `\d(\.\d+)?`.

Comment: (?:$|\|) This is what I want! Really thanks. And you remind me a risk that I will match the record like 12.5.5, but in the next code, I will try convert the number to float, so it will be okey as the wrong match will be ignore.